# Command raised an exception: ValueError: images do not match

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is a test command I did to test the welcome card and then put it in the event. But I get an error when resizing the user's avatar, this is the error: The command threw an exception: ValueError: Images do not match.

```py
 @commands.command()
 async def proof(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
   img = Image.open("img/cardwelcome.png")

   avatar_asset =  member.avatar_url_as(size = 4096)
   buffer_avatar = io.BytesIO(await avatar_asset.read())
   avatar_image = Image.open(buffer_avatar)
   avatar_image = avatar_image.resize((128, 200)) 
   circle_image = Image.new('L', (128, 128))
   circle_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle_image)
   circle_draw.ellipse((0, 0, 128, 128), fill=255)
   img.paste(avatar_image, (490, 140), circle_image)
   img.save("cardwelcome2.png")
   await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'img/cardwelcome2.png'))
```

I also have this other code that I am testing with, but I wouldn't know how to add the `resize` here, if anyone knows how to add it here or how to fix it in the other code I would greatly appreciate it:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def proof2(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    welcome = Image.open('img/cardwelcome.png')
    
    asset = member.avatar_url_as(size = 128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    img=Image.open(data).convert("RGB")
    npImage=np.array(img)
    h,w=img.size
    
    alpha = Image.new('L', img.size,0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
    draw.pieslice([0,0,h,w],0,360,fill=255)
    npAlpha=np.array(alpha)
    npImage=np.dstack((npImage,npAlpha))
    pfp = Image.fromarray(npImage)
    welcome.paste(pfp, (490, 140), alpha)
    welcome.save("img/cardwelcome2.png")
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'img/cardwelcome2.png'))
```

Comment: Give us the text of the exception including all of the stack info.   That should tell you what line of you code threw the error.

Comment: Emmh... That's all I get: Command raised an exception: ValueError: images do not match

Comment: discord.File consist of: file and filename, so you must add filename function. Because file .py and .png are on another folders, function discord.File freaking

Comment: Nonsense.   It does not just print "ValueError: Images do not match". 
 Read this to understand how to trace errors back to source. 
  https://realpython.com/python-traceback/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images aren't the same mode neither the same size.

```
 @commands.command()
 async def proof(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
   img = Image.open("img/cardwelcome.png")

   avatar_asset =  member.avatar_url_as(size = 4096)
   buffer_avatar = io.BytesIO(await avatar_asset.read())
   avatar_image = Image.open(buffer_avatar)
   avatar_image = avatar_image.resize((128, 200)) 
   circle_image = Image.new('L', (128, 128))
   circle_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle_image)
   circle_draw.ellipse((0, 0, 128, 128), fill=255)
   img.paste(avatar_image, (490, 140), circle_image)
   img.save("cardwelcome2.png")
   await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'img/cardwelcome2.png'))
```

So here the images should be the same, because when you paste it in the other image, you're masking the avatar_image. If they aren't the same size, the image can't be masked properly.

```
   avatar_image = avatar_image.resize((128, 200)) 
   circle_image = Image.new('L', (128, 128))
```

Just in the size value of circle_image put avatar_image.size:

```
   avatar_image = avatar_image.resize((128, 200)) 
   circle_image = Image.new('L', avatar_image.size)
```